# set algebra having union and minus

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using algebra of sets, show that:

$$A \cup (B\setminus C) = (A \cup B)\setminus (C\setminus A)$$

I have tried using venn diagram, and they come out to be equal. Please help on proving them equal using the laws of set algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A \cup (B\setminus C) = A⋃(B⋂C^c )=(A⋃B)⋂(A⋃C^c )=(A⋃B)\setminus(A⋃C^c )^c = (A⋃B)\setminus(A^c ⋂ C)=(A \cup B)\setminus (C\setminus A)$

here $A^c=U\setminus A$: complement of A